# Changing a variable in c++ and in c#

Tags: c++

When we want to change a value of a variable 
for example using swap : swap(x,y)
Why c# has an advantage over c++ in changing a variable value. (swap for example)
I guess because in c++ the swap function is already included in the functions library

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking here. It is not "better done" in C#...

Comment: sorry I'm new on stackoverflow I hope now it's understandable enough.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help at all. What advantage are you talking about?

Comment: And with >1 year on SO, you´re not new anymore...you could know how it works already

Comment: Advantage of the coding language. 
is the syntax simpler in c# ? 
is changing a variable value in c# less buggy ?
I have a course that analyses programming languages. 
Now sir you understand ?

Comment: @deviantfan I said I'm new on stackoverflow not on mathexchange.

Comment: If you think my body of the question is not understandable you are invited to help me write it better and edit it :)

Comment: Nope, I still don't understand. But if Fred did, and was able to satisfactorily answer your question, perhaps he could help you edit it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley My answer was just a shot in the blue. I'm still not sure if that's what OP was asking. And it seems neither is he ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow your answer is what I needed :)
so your shot was lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that puts some sense into your question is a readability aspect. If you see a function call in C++, you do not know whether the argument is passed by value or by reference:

```
// C++
int x = 42;
f(x);       // is x passed by value or by reference?
```

Whereas in C#, arguments that are passed by reference are visibly marked by the `ref` keyword:

```
// C#
int x = 42;
f(x);       // call by value
g(ref x);   // call by reference
```

Since you mentioned swap, that would look as follows:

```
// C++
std::swap(a, b);

// C#
YourFavoriteLibrary.swap(ref a, ref b);
```

Again, you can clearly see that `a` and `b` are passed by reference in C#.

Comment: thank you this could be an advantage.